# have a programming project for an intro c++ class one of the function we need to create is a split function

Tags: c++, function, split

i was hoping to get some feedback on if i am doing this the "smart way" or if maybe i could be doing it faster. if i were splitting on white spaces
i would probably use getline(stringstream, word, delimiter)
but i didnt know how to adapt the delimiter to all the good characters so i just looped through the whole string generated a new word until i reached a bad character but as i am fairly new to programming im not sure if its the best way to do it 
thanks for any feedback

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <string> 
            using std::string;
            #include <vector> 
            using std::vector;
            #include <sstream>
            #include <algorithm>
            #include <iterator> //delete l8r

            using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;
            /*
            void split(string line, vector<string>&words, string good_chars)
            o
            Find words in the line that consist of good_chars. 
            Any other character is considered a separator. 
            o
            Once you have a word, convert all the characters to lower case.

            You then push each word onto the reference vector words.
            Important: split goes  in  its  own  file.  This  is  both  for  your  own  benefit,  you  can  reuse 
            split, and for grading purposes.We will provide a split.h for you.
            */
            void split(string line, vector<string> & words, string good_chars){
                string good_word;
                for(auto c : line){
                    if(good_chars.find(c)!=string::npos){
                        good_word.push_back(c);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(good_word.size()){
                            std::transform(good_word.begin(), good_word.end(), good_word.begin(), ::tolower);
                            words.push_back(good_word);
                        }
                        good_word = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            int main(){
                vector<string> words;
                string good_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'";
                // TEST split
                split("This isn't a TEST.", words, good_chars);
                // words should have: {"this", "isn't", "a", "test"}, no period in test
                std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ","));
                cout << endl;
                return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this is a reasonable approach given the context of an intro to C++ class. I'd even say that it's fairly likely that this is the approach your instructor expects to see.

There are, of course, a few optimization tweaks that can be done. Like instantiating a 256-element `bool` array, using `good_chars` to set the corresponding values to `true`, and all others defaulting to `false`, then replacing the `find()` call with a quick array lookup.

But, I'd predirect that if you were to hand in such a thing, you'll be suspected of copying stuff you found on the intertubes, so leave that alone.

One thing you might consider doing is using `tolower` when you `push_back` each character, instead, and removing the extra `std::transform` pass over the word.